# How to convert analog signals (i.e. from a pulse rate sensor) into digital signals in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

This is my first post. Like the title says, how can I convert analog signals, like from a pulse rate sensor, into digital signals so that I can read the pulse rate using something like Java?

That's basically the gist of it, and before anyone asks, I have found questions like this but I still didn't really understand.

So thanks for helping.

Comment: 1) Arduino is not Java, it's C++. 2) A simple google search would have given you the answer: https://www.google.de/search?site=&source=hp&q=analogread+arduino&oq=analog+read+arduiono&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i13k1l4.741.3276.0.4180.20.14.0.0.0.0.335.2276.0j6j4j1.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..9.11.2275...0j0i10k1.HSHNMHrAG-A

Comment: No, I know that, both of those. What I mean is converting electrical/analog signals into something like data I can see on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "pulse rate sensor", you mean something that measures your heart rate, then I assume you are dealing with an operational amplifier (op-amp) circuit that outputs **analog** signals

By **analog**, I mean the signal is a voltage that varies over time.

In Arduino, there is a built-in command called `analogRead(some pin # here)` which measures the voltage at that instant and returns a 10-bit number, (that is, ranging from 0-1023). This process is called ADC (Analog to Digital Conversion). For more info on ADC, try this [tutorial/article](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/analog-to-digital-conversion) by Sparkfun Electronics.

In your question you mentioned that you wish to read the data into a Java application (as I understand). So how about something like this:

On your arduino:

```
// ...

void loop() {
  // read voltage from 0-5V on pin A0 and store it in our sample buffer
  int sample = analogRead(A0);

  Serial.println(sample);
  delay(10);
}
```

This will continuously send your converted digital signals over Serial so that you can connect the arduino via USB to your computer, which is running a Java application.

There are many ways to read a USB serial port in Java, but the library I recommend is [jssc](https://javalibs.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc) because it feels simililar to Arduino's Serial library.

[Here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wikis/jSSC_examples.wiki) are some JSSC examples

the main one you are concerned with is how to read the serial port:

```
import jssc.SerialPort; import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
    try {
        serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
        byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(10);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
        serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

}
```

In your case, you should:

1. declare a global buffer for samples
2. run `serialPort = ...`, `serialPort.openPort()`, and `serialPort.setParams(...)`
3. in a loop, use `serialPort.readBytes(...)` in a try...catch block to store data in your buffer
4. once you have enough data, you break from the loop to analyze it (for heartbeats, etc...)

I will leave it up to you how you wish to display your data. Happy coding :)

Comment: Only thing I would add : Arduino is not ideal to use as a DAC. If you want you can use NI MyDAC which will be less error prone and will give you more accurate results moreover you can use labview along with that which is more ideal for hardware projects